# Find pattern and move it to end of line

Tags: string, bash, sed

I am looking for a solution that would allow me to find a pattern between the characters `/` and `s_` and move it to the end of the line.

I assume the following string:

```
"s_check_login_password= s_comm_type=TCPIP s_dest_address=10.55.28.125/22 s_org_address= s_net_proxy= s_ft_proxy="
```

From this, I want to get the value just after the `/` of the `s_dest_address` field: `22`,  and move it to the end of the line.

I tried this:

```
sed 's/\([^/\]*[^ s_]* s_\)\(.*;\)/\2\1/'
```

but I guess it's not the good way. Is there any way to do it with sed?

Comment: end of the file or end of the line?

Comment: with sed I don't know, you'd have to use GREP and AWK. `$var = $(echo $string | grep "s_dest_address" | awk -F"/" '{print $1}'`) -> then, `sed "s/$var//"` --> then `sed "s/something_to_reach_the_end_of_the_file/$var/"` -> but like above, file?

Comment: End of the line, sorry ! i just edited the question.

Comment: I tried your solution, but it cut everything after the `/`, even the next field

Comment: Right, I forgot, `awk -F"/||\ " '{print $1}' ` Not sure if using `\ ` match a space. I'm not giving directly the answer because I have no way for testing it before answering you

Comment: if the end of the line IS ALWAYS `s_ft_proxy="` then: `sed "s/s_ft_proxy=\"/s_ft_proxy=\"$var/"`

Comment: Thank you for your time, but it seems still to cut the content, anyway someone gave me the solution above. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have not pasted the expected output so based on your summary of question only I have written this.

```
awk 'match($0,/\/[^ s]*/){print substr($0,1,RSTART),substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1),substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)}' Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
match($0,/\/[^ s]*/){
  print substr($0,1,RSTART),substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1),substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
}
'   Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

```
awk '
match($0,/\/[^ s]*/){  ##Using match utility to match the REGEX where it should match from / to space s and if REGEX match found then do following:
  print substr($0,1,RSTART),substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1),substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1) ##Printing substring from 1st character to till value of RSTART then print substring from value of RSTART+RLENGTH+1 to till end then print substring from RSTART+1 value to till RLENGTH-1 value. Basically RSTART and RLENGTH are the out of the box variable for awk which will be SET when a match is found of REGEX, where RSTART is starting index of match and RLENGTH is the length of the REGEX match.
}
' Input_file           ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Could you please explain to me the command, i would like to understand to avoid asking the same question another day ?

Comment: @f1rstsurf, sure added explanation too now in post, kindly do let me know in case of any queries, cheers.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, awk is sometimes a bit hard to understand :)

Comment: i noticed that with the command above, if there more than 1 occurence of `/` followed by `s`, it's gonna occur on it too. So i tried to change the command to something like this `awk 'match($0,/address=[^\/]*\/[^ s]*/)`, but it return the following output `s_dest_a  ddress='x.x.x.x/x`. Could you please help me to catch only the `s_dest_address` field ?

Comment: @f1rstsurf, not sure if I get it, could you please post some example of it not sure if in the same thread or not. Samples of input and samples of output will help to understand it more.

Comment: Sorry, what i mean is : if in my file i have the following fields : `s_comments='Serveur Prolog/BCS de recette'` and `s_dest_a ddress='x.x.x.x/x`, which both contains a `/`, by using the command in your post, both of the field are gonna be cut like this : `s_comments='Serveur Prolog/ de recette' BCS
s_dest_address='10.55.47.82/  3517'`, however, I only want to proceed action on the `s_dest_address` field, that's why i would like to filter awk with `s_dest_address` string

Comment: @f1rstsurf, I am sorry, I am really not getting it. Could you please update your post and let me know on same. With proper examples.

Comment: @f1rstsurf, ok maybe I got it could you please try `awk 'match($0,/s_dest_address=[^ ]*/){split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),array,"/");print substr($1,1,RSTART-1) array[1] substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1),array[2]}'  Input_file` and let me know if this helps? Once confirmed I will add this into Solution too then.

Answer (score 0):

With sed

```
sed -E 's#(.*/)([^ ]*)(.*)#\1\3\2#' infile
```

- Change `/` to `#` as sed expression separator so there's no need to escape it.
- `([^ ]*)` your expected match (22).
- `(.*)`the rest of the string.
- `\1\3\2` change the order in which capturing groups are returned.